# Prove: $P(X>a)\ge\frac{(1-a)^2}{b}$ for every $0<a<1$

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, random-variables

I found this question and I have no idea how to solve it. I'll be glad if you can help me!
$$$$

let $X>0$ be a random variable, such that: $E(X)=1,\quad E(X^2)=b$

Then, for every $0<a<1$, prove that: $P(X>a)\ge\frac{(1-a)^2}{b}$
$$$$

If we were talking about upper bound, i would've start thinking about Markov or Chebyshev inequality, but it's not... So I'm out of ideas.

Comment: See [Paley-Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality).

Comment: Oh wow that was straight forward.. Thanks! Can you prove this inequality? I didn't fully understood it in Wikipedia. It looks like they skipped some steps

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand
$$1=E(X)=E(X\mathbf 1_{\{X\le a\}})+E(X\mathbf1_{\{X>a\}})\le a+E(X\mathbf1_{\{X>a\}}),$$
giving $E(X\mathbf 1_{\{X>a\}})\ge1-a>0$, and thus $E(X\mathbf 1_{\{X>a\}})^2\ge(1-a)^2$. On the other hand,
by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$E(X\mathbf 1_{\{X>a\}})^2\le E(X^2)E(\mathbf 1_{\{X>a\}})=b\,P(X>a).$$
Therefore $b\,P(X>a)\ge(1-a)^2$.

Comment: What does this $E(X1_{X\leqslant a})$ means? And why does it $E(X1_{X\leqslant a}) \leqslant a$ ?

Comment: @ryden If $A$ is an event (e.g., $A=\{X\le a\}$), then $\omega\mapsto\mathbf 1_A(\omega)$ is the random variable that is $1$ if $\omega\in A$ (e.g., $X(\omega)\le a$) and $0$ otherwise. In other words $E(X\mathbf 1_{\{X\le a\}})$ is the expectation of $X$ **on the event** $\{X\le a\}$. It is clearly $\le a$ because precisely $X\le a$ there.